# Android Background data transfer rates

Tags: android

Does anyone know why I see slower data transfer rates for the same app running in the background on Android 4.1 devices than I did on an Android 4.03 device ?

Data transfer rates when the app is in the foreground are unaffected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find any definitive information on this.  My assumption is that there may be some processor throttling when in background to preserve battery life

Comment: Is the process being cached? (Just throwing ideas around)